# Injecting surface for drawing a webview's html 5 video on

Tags: android, video, webview, opengl-es

I tried to succesfully render a webview onto a GLSurfaceView, which I managed to do thanks to this:
[Is it possible to render an Android View to an OpenGL FBO or texture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12499396/is-it-possible-to-render-an-android-view-to-an-opengl-fbo-or-texture/29066625#29066625)

However when I tried to load up a website with a video, I realized, that the video doesn't play on the GLSurfaceView (there is sound however). I found out through googleing that the webview renders the video on a seperate surfaceview, which is probably the cause, that it doesnt appear on my GLSurfaceView.

My question:
How do I go about hacking the webview in order to access the extra video surface?

I consciously say *hack*... I am ready to use reflection and whatever is needed, but I don't really know where to start. In the SDK Manager provided source all I can find is the WebViewProvider *interface* without any implementation. Via grepcode I find some kind of implementations (http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/4.1.2_r1-robolectric-0/android/webkit/HTML5VideoViewProxy.java), but not in the SDK Manager supplied stuff. I am running KitKat 4.4 on an Xiaomi RedMi 2 phone.

How can I determine/use the relevant implementation?
Or do you think this isn't even feasable?

Comment: Hey, did you find any solution?

Comment: Sadly no... I can't remember any details about what I tried, so I can't share any further insights on this :(

Answer (score 0):

With a `WebView` I don't think it's possible, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19273437/android-draw-youtube-video-on-surfacetexture). I'm currently attempting something similar with a `GeckoView` because the you can get a handle to the surface, see [this](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/mobile-firefox-dev/2017-November/002363.html) note and [this](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/GeckoView) on how to embed a `GeckoView` into your project.