# Does Android OpenGL have an off-screen function for drawbitmap performance

Tags: android, performance, opengl-es, android-camera, android-mediarecorder

I have an Android app (targetSdkVersion 28) that combines 2 TextureViews each showing a camera view into 1 bitmap then uses drawbitmap to a mediarecorder surface for recording. This is being called from the onSurfaceTextureUpdated. This seems to bottle neck it down to around 8 to 10 frames per second in the final video.

Does anyone know if OpenGL can achieve this in a more frame rate efficient way or if the below code can be made more performant?

I have tried moving creating the Bitmap and Canvas outside of the function and while it is slightly better, the combined bitmap has flicker.

```
class thScreenShot extends AsyncTask{

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {

        try {

            List<TextureView> tilingViews = getAllTextureViews(rootLayout);
            if (tilingViews.size() > 0) {
                final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
                final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
                for (TextureView tilingTextureView : tilingViews) {
                    Bitmap bitmap1 = tilingTextureView.getBitmap(tilingTextureView.getWidth(), tilingTextureView.getHeight());
                    int[] location = new int[2];
                    tilingTextureView.getLocationInWindow(location);
                    Rect dest = new Rect(location[0], location[1], bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
                    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap1, dest, dest, null);
                }
                if (isRecording) {
                     if (surfaceS == null)
                     {
                          surfaceS = mMediaRecorder.getSurface();
                     }
                     synchronized (surfaceS) {
                          canvasS = surfaceS.lockHardwareCanvas();
                          canvasS.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
                          surfaceS.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvasS);
                          FPSCount++;
                     }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

public List<TextureView> getAllTextureViews(View view)
{
    List<TextureView> tilingViews = new ArrayList<TextureView>();
    if (view instanceof TextureView) {
        tilingViews.add((TextureView)view);
    }
    else if(view instanceof ViewGroup)
    {
        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup)view;
        for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
            tilingViews.addAll(getAllTextureViews(viewGroup.getChildAt(i)));
        }
    }
    return tilingViews;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you need UI rendering to texture or normal render to texture, probably one of them. You can check for example [Is it possible to render an Android View to an OpenGL FBO or texture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12499396/is-it-possible-to-render-an-android-view-to-an-opengl-fbo-or-texture) and https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/41887/how-to-render-small-texture-on-another-texture

Also remember to always check https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Common_Mistakes

Comment: Thanks for that. Will check it all out. Cheers.